# How to remove display none in the option field?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a problem to remove the `display: none;` in the option field when I've the button.

Below is my coding, first start I have added the display:none in the `Only User`:

```html
 <div class="form-group">
 <label>Edit Katalaluan<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;*</span></label>
 <select class="form-control required" id="edit_password" name="edit_password">
 <option value="0">Super Admin</option>
 <option value="1" style="display:none;">Only User</option>                                 
 </select>
 </div>
```

Then I click the `Edit` button then the `style="display:none;"` will remove， below is edit button coding:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="viewFunc2('<?php echo $loc; ?>', '<?php echo $id; ?>')" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-color-format="hex">Edit</a>
```

Below is my button javascript function:

```html
function viewFunc2(act_file, filter_id) {
    var loading_gif = $('#loading_gif');
    var form_data = 'action=view&filter_id=' + filter_id;

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '?f=' + act_file,
        data: form_data,
        beforeSend: function() {
            // show_overLay();
            loading_gif.show();
            remove_errorMsg();

            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            loading_gif.hide();

            // alert(data.id);
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $('#myForm #' + key).val('');

                $('#myForm #' + key).val(value);
                // $('#' + key + '_' + value).attr('selected','selected');
                // console.log(key + ': ' + value);
            });
            viewFuncDetail(act_file, filter_id);

            $('#user_name').prop('readonly', true);
            $('#filter_id').val(data.id);
            $('#btn_save').val('Update');
            $('#btn_cancel').val('Cancel');

        },
        error: function(data) {
            loading_gif.hide();
            alert(AJAX_ERR_MSG);
        }
    })
}
```

What I have tried:

```html
document.getElementById(id).style.removeProperty( 'display' );
```

But it doesn't work, it show me the result like below:

[image: output1]

Hope someone can guide me on how to add the remove `style=" display: none;"` function in the javascript when I click the Edit button. Thanks.

Comment: In your HTML your onclick function is viewFunc2('<?php echo $loc; ?>', '<?php echo $id; ?>
that means it will come like this viewFunc256791. 
But in your js you called the function name only viewFunc2.
That means your HTML and js function name are not same, that's it;s not working, try to match that same function name in both HTML and js

Comment: Ok. I have trie this document.getElementById(id).style.removeProperty( 'display' ); but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Make a class like
`.hide{display:none;}`

after making a class in your css you need to Write JQuery code like this

```
$('#edit_password option[value="1"]').addClass('hide');
```

And for show that option you can write

```
$('#edit_password option[value="1"]').removeClass('hide');
```

That's How You can Manage it as per Your Requirement

Answer (score 2):

To show the option with the value 1 (this removes `display: none`):

```
$('#edit_password option[value="1"]').show();
```

And to hide it again:

```
$('#edit_password option[value="1"]').hide();
```

Comment: May I know your method is added to where?

Comment: Well, I guess in your success: function(data) {}